# ObjC: Reorder controls before View is showing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view, asynchronous, request

I'm dynamically creating TextFields in the requestFinished-Method.
But (I think) because of the asynchronous request my view has finished loading and so the user can see the TextFields getting visible and "reorder" my button (created with InterfaceBuilder).

Is it possible that this happens until my view is shown.
For example with a MBProgressHUD till it has finished?

Thanks and sorry for the bad english ;)
Greets Michael

Comment: Do you mean your textfields are coming and overlapping the button that you add from xib?

Comment: No I mean that I see moving the button and displaying every single textfield instead of displaying the whole view (with the correct moved textfields and button).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the controls before the view is shown, then move then in `viewWillAppear` instead of (I assume) where you are doing it in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can still see the moving TextFields. Alternative: Is it possible to start a MBProgressHUD at a parent-view and stop it at the child-view? Maybe this would also look okay.